# Area under the curve of a contour plot created with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, contour, integral

I have used matplotlib to create a contour plot. The code is very simple and reads as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.contour(result_array, levels=[0,10,20],colors = ('white','red','black',))
plt.show()
```

At this point, I would like to measure the area under the curve of each line created by the contour plot. Any option between integrate, simps, trapz could in principle work. My issue is that I am unable to extract the numerical values of the contour plot and I am not sure what their spacing is. Any tip?

Comment: An intimidating, but correct answer is go read the source https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/contour.py Also look into the scikit-image's marching cube implementation.

Comment: I had this problem, try this 

  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26121220/4079533